# Procedure not returning or modifying any rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Below is my procedure that is not modifying any records. When I run it in peices everything works. I'm assuming I'm not using my variables correctly. Can anyone confirm? Thanks.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE a, b, c, d, e INT;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a.team_id, a.league_id, a.bid, f.roster_id, f.winning_team_id FROM kl_faa f, kl_faa_audit a, faa_times t WHERE t.id = f.faa_times_id AND f.id = a.faa_id AND f.auction_end_date IS NULL AND (DATE_ADD(f.last_bid_date, INTERVAL t.hours HOUR)) <= NOW() AND a.faa_id != (SELECT MAX(ref_id) FROM kl_faa_audit WHERE faa_id = a.faa_id);
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO a, b, c, d, e;
UPDATE kl_user_league SET cash_balance = cash_balance + @c    WHERE league_id = @b and team_id = @a;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;

UPDATE kl_team_roster SET team_id = @e, status = 0 WHERE roster_id = @d;

UPDATE kl_faa f LEFT JOIN faa_times t ON t.id = f.faa_times_id
SET f.auction_end_date = NOW()
WHERE t.id = f.faa_times_id AND f.auction_end_date IS NULL AND (DATE_ADD(f.last_bid_date, INTERVAL t.hours HOUR)) <= NOW();
END;
END
```

Comment: `@a`, `@b`, `@c`, `@d` and `@e` are [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html). `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are [13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html), are different variables.

Comment: So in my update for instance, I can just use the a,b,c? And get rid of the @ everywhere?

Comment: That's right. A statement like this: `UPDATE kl_team_roster SET team_id = e, status = 0 WHERE roster_id = d;` should do the job.

Comment: I changed it, but I still get this message: 0 rows affected by the last statement inside the procedure.

Comment: It would require the structure of the tables involved, as well as some test data to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: It should also improve the way that the cursor ends to ensure that the latest statements (`UPDATE`) run.

Comment: Is there a way to debug a procedure in phpmyadmin?